# biosdevname is giving me "p120p1" instead of p1p1 -- is this correct?

Tags: networkcard

I'm using biosdevname on a CentOS 6.3 server to name my interfaces in a rational way. On our new Dell PowerEdge C6145, we have 2 embedded ports and two PCI cards with 4 ports each.

On our other Dell 815 servers with a similar configuration, we get em1, em2, (and actually em3 and em4 on those), and then p1p1, p1p2, p1p3, p1p4, and p2p1, p2p2, p2p3, p2p4.

For whatever reason *this* system gives "120" for the slot number rather than 1. Now, I can accept that it might not be slot one internally, but it's definitely also not the one hundred and twentieth.

I updated to biosdevname 0.4.1 from Fedora Rawhide but am getting the same result.

Since our puppet configuration is expecting the other names, this is a hassle. We can work around it, but I'd rather only do the workaround if there is a rational explanation — either a bug needing a temporary fix, or something that I don't understand which makes the large number actually sensible.

So, is there such a explanation?

Comment: Do `lspci`, `lshw`, or `dmidecode` shed any light?

Comment: What are you using the `p1p1`-like names for?  Perhaps there's a better way?